# How to control or select list item in pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto, listitem

```
   |    | GroupBox - 'HPF'    (L775, T613, R882, B893)
   |    | ['HPF', 'HPFGroupBox', 'GroupBox2', 'HPF0', 'HPF1']
   |    | child_window(title="HPF", control_type="Group")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | ListBox - ''    (L775, T613, R882, B893)
   |    |    | ['ListBox']
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | ListItem - 'HPF'    (L775, T621, R882, B659)
   |    |    |    | ['HPF2', 'ListItem', 'HPFListItem', 'ListItem0', 'ListItem1']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="HPF", control_type="ListItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | ListItem - 'LPF'    (L775, T658, R882, B697)
   |    |    |    | ['LPF', 'ListItem2', 'LPFListItem']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="LPF", control_type="ListItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | ListItem - 'Peak/Dip'    (L775, T696, R882, B734)
   |    |    |    | ['Peak/DipListItem', 'Peak/Dip', 'ListItem3']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Peak/Dip", control_type="ListItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | ListItem - 'Notch'    (L775, T733, R882, B772)
   |    |    |    | ['NotchListItem', 'ListItem4', 'Notch']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Notch", control_type="ListItem")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | ListItem - 'HighShelf'    (L775, T771, R882, B809)
   |    |    |    | ['HighShelf', 'HighShelfListItem', 'ListItem5']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="HighShelf", control_type="ListItem")
```

How to control or select that listitem in pywinauto

now how to select that items

```
app = dlg.ListBox.texts()
print(app)
```

Output:
[['HPF'], ['LPF'], ['Peak/Dip'], ['Notch'], ['HighShelf'], ['LowShelf'], ['AllPass']]

i tried that thing and i have received output as mentioned here.

Now want to expect to select particular 1 item

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
dlg.ListBox.Select([index of item in list])
```

You can also read the docs[https://readthedocs.org/projects/pywinauto/downloads/pdf/stable/]

[Select the ListBox item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eRQR.png)